# React useContext keep data after redirect?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I wanna keep the username after login in a Context to access it later. The Context works fine but after redirecting the user to the Home the Context value is gone.

When i set the Context after the login is successfully, it works like it should..

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

**Login.js**

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../contexts/UserContext";

const { setUser, user } = useContext(UserContext);

async function handleLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (username && password) {
      await fetch("http://localhost:5000/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        credentials: "include",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: username,
          password: password,
        }),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          if (data.error) {
            setLoginError(data.error);
            return;
          } else {
            setUser(data);
            console.log(user);
            window.location.assign("/");
          }
        })
    }
  }
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../contexts/UserContext";

const Home = () => {
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <p>{user.username}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**App.js**

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";

import IncludeLayout from "./helper/IncludeLayout";
import ExcludeLayout from "./helper/ExcludeLayout";
import ProtectedRoutes from "./helper/ProtectedRoutes";

import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Users from "./pages/Users";

import { UserContext } from "./contexts/UserContext";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<ExcludeLayout />}>
            <Route exact path="login" element={<Login />} />
          </Route>
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
            <Route element={<IncludeLayout />}>
              <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route exact path="/users" element={<Users />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from Samathingamajig i figured out this solution that works for me:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const navi = useNavigate();
navi("/");
```

instead of using useHistory.

Answer (score 1):

Use `useNavigate` from react-router-dom

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../contexts/UserContext";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const navigate = useNavigate(); 
const { setUser, user } = useContext(UserContext);

async function handleLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    

    if (username && password) {
      await fetch("http://localhost:5000/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        credentials: "include",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: username,
          password: password,
        }),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          if (data.error) {
            setLoginError(data.error);
            return;
          } else {
            setUser(data);
            console.log(user);
            navigate("/");
            //window.location.assign("/");
          }
        })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but useHistory is no longer supported in v6, but this kicked me in the right direction. I post the correction for v6 below.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is that you have not persisted the data to browser storage so when routed to another page the data will be lost there is no workaround it just persist the data or persist some kind of auth token so later you can check if there is token and if there is send it to the server to get the user detail if you do this using useEffct then save the data to the context it will work, you can have the useEffect in the app.js so that anytime a user routes to any page the useEffect will fire, if you want this functionality tell me and ill clarify more and alos show you how to do it.

Comment: "there is no workaround" yes there is, you can change the route without losing state and/or refreshing.

Comment: oh yeah somewhat my mistake tho I do think it's tiresome to pass the state with the route every time and you do have to know that people are not always using your link buttons to navigate through your app, and if you say you can update the data with another API call every time a user refreshes or navigates without your link buttons, I think that solution is almost the same as what i listed above just less neet. cheers

Comment: but if you wanna do what you just said then do pass the state with every link/route though your app or through the parts of your app that need user data, i think it's easy to do so with the new react-router